# CEditBox or CListBox which one is better for big amout of logging data

Tags: c++, listbox, editbox

This always was a big question for me that for a very big amount of logs (like 100,000 line log) which one is better in performance, scrolling,... also consider formatting the text with color is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the circumstances, I'd probably use a listbox.

1. You can create a virtual listbox to support lots of items relatively well.
2. Neither supports color<sup>1</sup> but owner-drawn listboxes are easier.
3. Edit controls are "flow" oriented, not line oriented.

<sup>1</sup>Other than one foreground and one background color.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used a read-only richedit edit control for this sort of thing because:

- You can offer the ability to copy lines to the clipboard.
- It is easy to add text formatting (colour, bold, italic, etc.)
- Writing the data to a file is simple (you can get the text using a GetWindowText call.)